# View changes for specific commit by hash?

Tags: git

If I run `git log -5` I get a summary of the last 5 commits.  How can I view the *details* (specifically changes) of one of those commits using the hash output from `git log`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

git show `<commit-id>` what you are looking for.

[Documentation for git show](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-show)

Comment: Well, talk about bad luck or stupidity, I tried that first but apparently the one I tested was a merge and there were no changes, only the message, so I thought it wasn't what I wanted.  Thanks!

Comment: @ScottBeeson No issue :). Happy to help anyway. Accept the answer if helped.

Comment: Have to wait 2 minutes :)

Comment: Ok. I didn't knew this.